# mysql time events aren't executed

Tags: mysql, events

I need to execute a query at given time. I read about mysql events, and they seemed as a way to go. I made this test example:

```
CREATE EVENT deleteUserJourney
    ON SCHEDULE AT '2011-02-05 13:16:00'
    DO
      DELETE FROM User_has_Journey WHERE idSell=7;
```

But at the given time nothing happened. Mysql time is ok (at least NOW() returns correct value) event creation query didn't return any errors/warnings. The strange thing is that I cannot create new Event with the same name, although I read that events should be destroyed after they are executed.

If it is important, the mysql version is:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you turned on the Event Scheduler? Try:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: yep, that 's it. Thanks a lot.